# Why does reduce not work on Struct?

Tags: swift, struct, reduce

I have the following code

```
struct Tab {
  var origin:CGFloat
  var width:CGFloat
  init(width:CGFloat) {
    origin = 0
    self.width = width
  }
}

let subTabs = [Tab(width:1), Tab(width:2)]
let w =  reduce(subTabs, CGFloat(0), { $0.width + $1.width })
```

and would expect the `reduce` to sum up the `width`s in my struct. But it raises a compiler error (you can test in Playground).

Comment: Wow. I love SO. Down vote immediately. Go vote yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function that reduce needs takes 2 arguments: the accumulated value and the next item in the sequence. Your function is expecting two sequence items (`Tab` structs). Since you are returning a float, the accumluted value is a float, and not a `Tab` as you expect. The correct call is:

```
let w =  reduce(subTabs, CGFloat(0), { $0 + $1.width })
```

Comment: Well, I love SO. Answers immediately :-) Thanks. This is it.

Comment: @juan can you explain why the first one doesn't need to be $0.width? Thank you